# div scrolls to top after refresh need to stop auto scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a div that refreshes every 2 seconds  to stop scrolling back to the top after the 2 second refresh I have PHP code and javascript. The Javascript I am using is:

```
function at_Ticket_scrollBottom()
{
   var objDiv = document.getElementById("cartTicket");
   objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}

function at_Tabs_Update()
{

if(div_WPOSVar_IsVisible())
{
    //calling setTimeout without clearing any existing timeout can add multiple calls.
    //IE the normal 2 second sequence, then call at_Tabs_Update two more times, and
    //     now we have 3 timeouts set to call at_Tabs again, etc.
    //This wouldn't be an issue except that we call at_Tabs_Update directly to cause
    //     immediate refresh from many places.
    //So clear the handle everytime to get rid of the last one we set.
    clearTimeout(at_Tabs_Timer);
    at_Tabs_Timer=setTimeout("at_Tabs_Update()", 2*1000); //every 2 seconds
    return;
}
}
```

So after the refresh if I scroll down to the bottom of the ticket it jumps back to the top after the next refresh so I can never get to the bottom and select an item and edit it before the refresh how do I stop the auto scroll back to the top.

Comment: How are you refreshing the div?

Comment: i have added a section showing the refresh code please let me know if you need more.

Comment: That doesn't actually show what's happening during a refresh, just shows how you are clearing your timeouts.

Comment: A side note, don't pass strings to `setTimeout` -- pass function references: `setTimeout(at_Tabs_Update, 2000);` === doing it right

Comment: Hello Chris and thank you for joining in on this question. Do you know of any other ways to make it stop jumping to the bottom of the div after it does its 2 second refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the scars infos I can gather here I think your best bet would be to save your current scroll position before you refresh and after the ajax call scroll to that saved position.
use jQuerys [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function for both reading and setting the scroll.

some pseudo code for illustration:

```
at ajax refresh function
    var curPos $(element).scrollTop();
    ... do ajax call ..
        ajax callback: $(element).scrollTop(curPos);
```

Comment: I don't know where to place this code i am using ajax php and javascript in this program but cant figure out where to put this information.

Comment: that's not real code but pseudo code to illustrate what to do.